# Custom Visual Studio Errors

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, build-error

Using Visual Studio 2012/2013 Professional...

I'm wondering if there's a way to define customized C# error conditions in Visual Studio. I know that there's already a way to toggle certain error conditions to show as build errors (e.g. show warnings are errors, etc.)

In particular, I want to write some sort of *thing* that looks for class objects that have MEF `[Import]` tags over them, and then show a build error in the case that they get referenced in a constructor. (i.e. rather than `OnImportsSatisfied()`)

Comment: That sounds more like a Code Analysis rule. You can write custom code analysis rules - [here's how to do it in Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx) which I think also applies to Visual Studio 2012/2013.

Comment: This looks like it might be what I want. I'll have to do some tinkering with it to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, this functionality called: "Code Analysis".
Microsoft uses this in Visual Studio compiler as well.

You can create custom rules on your own.
Take a look at this code which demonstrates how to create a custom rule:

```
using Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk;

namespace MyCustomFxCopRules
{

    internal abstract class BaseFxCopRule : BaseIntrospectionRule
    {
        protected BaseFxCopRule(string ruleName) 
            : base(ruleName, "DukesFirstFxCopRule.DukesFirstFxCopRule", typeof(BaseFxCopRule).Assembly)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

You can take a look at [this guide](https://weblogs.asp.net/spano/how-to-add-a-custom-rule-to-vsts-code-analysis).

Please take into account this requires Premium or Ultimate version of Visual Studio.

Comment: This is perfect. I've moved on from my original issue since I posted this over a year ago - but I can think of more than a few places in my class libraries where this would be useful now! I don't have VS Premium or Ultimate, but I'm gonna bet that this is applicable to Professional which I am (I'll report back on this too)

Comment: @darkpbj any update on the availability of this on the professional version ?